# Kendo UI DatePicker Warning on date format yyyy-MM-dd

Tags: date, kendo-ui, datepicker, format

I have a warning on my page about of an invalid date format as you can see below. The warning is generated by Kendo UI DatePicker component. I can't find a solutions on the web, my app is localized pt-BR. How to solve this problem.

```
<p>@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("periodoDocumento").Value(DateTime.Now))</p>
```

Error in Google Chrome:

```
The specified value '06/07/2015' does not conform to the required format, 'yyyy-MM-dd'.
```

**I must use day-month-year format for my client needs.**

Answer (score 19):

I found solution:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("periodoDocumento").Value(DateTime.Now).HtmlAttributes(new { @type = "" }))
```

So jquery will stop parsing this field as date with default format.

Comment: That worked for me.  I guess chrome is taking the `type="date"` and trying to do it's own date picker, which generates the warning since it is not a valid date format that chrome supports, even though Kendo deals with it properly.

Comment: This nailed it for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Setting the field's type to `text` prevents the browser, and jQuery Validator from treating it as a date. This is a little cleaner than specifying an invalid input type format (like `empty string`).

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
    .Name("DateFieldName")
    .Value(Model.DateFieldName)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @type=  "text"})
    )
```

However, this is still a bit of a hack - it just suppresses the validation done by your browser and/or validation tools upon date fields. The better solution (suitable for a long-term fix) is to ensure the date strings populating these date fields conform to the [HTML5 date field living standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#date-state-(type=date)) spelled out in the [ISO 8601](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/iso8601.htm), e.g., `2017-02-10`

Also reference this newer question, specifically about Chrome now requiring correct formatting on HTML5 date fields.

[Kendo UI datepicker incompatible with Chrome 56](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41945417/kendo-ui-datepicker-incompatible-with-chrome-56/41956630?noredirect=1#comment71458371_41956630)

Answer (score 2):

Add the format property:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Format("dd/MM/yyyy").Name("periodoDocumento").Value(DateTime.Now))
```

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datepicker#configuration-format

Comment: The error persists, also auditioned with DMY in .format, since the date is DMY.

But without success.

Comment: Is the error only in Chrome? http://www.telerik.com/forums/support-input-error-using-latest-chrome-dev-build

Comment: Yes, only in chrome, but i'm not using canary, i'm using Chrome, version  43.0.2357.130.

Comment: Not that it should matter, but my setup is @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.MyDate).Format("dd/MM/yyyy")  I don't use the name or value properties and populate the initial model value in the controller. Might want to check Chrome Dev tools to see what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this 
`.HtmlAttributes(new { type = "text" })`