# Kendo DatePickerFor issue in Chrome version 56.0.2924

Tags: html, google-chrome, kendo-ui, html-input, kendo-datepicker

I am using Kendo DatePickerFor.

After I recently updated my Chrome browser, it shows a blank value in the date picker control. I am using it for month selection with `MMM yyyy` format.

Can anybody please help me out?

My previous chrome version was `55.0.2883` and it was working perfectly fine.

My code in view file is:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.FromDate).Start(CalendarView.Year).Depth(CalendarView.Year).Format("MMM yyyy"))
```

Comment: Could be the same issue as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41945417/6441048)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kendo UI datepicker incompatible with Chrome 56](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41945417/kendo-ui-datepicker-incompatible-with-chrome-56)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fixed the problem for me:
http://www.telerik.com/forums/date-field-not-rendering-correct-in-browsers-that-support-html-5

> Some browsers with native support for "date" type (Chrome in particular) validate the set value and if it is not in the correct format (a valid full-date as defined in [RFC 3339]) then it is ignored. For now you can change the type the input to "text" permanently and avoid any issues related with the native inputs

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
     .Name("datepicker")
     .Value("10/10/2011")
     .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "text" })
)
```

Comment: what about  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.date, new { HtmlAttributes = new { type="text"} }) . it is still gives error