# Kendo datepicker not working

Tags: kendo-ui

In current chrome version (56.0.2924.87), Kendo date and time picker value is not coming correctly. This was working perfectly in previous version. I have given now() as date picker value with type date from my mobile Kendo date and time picker works perfectly, but not in browser. It was working before.

Comment: Please share code and details

Comment: Could be the same issue as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41945417/kendo-ui-datepicker-incompatible-with-chrome-56)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
     .Name("datepicker")
     .Value("10/10/2011")
     .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "text" })
)
```

See these posts:

- [Kendo DatePickerFor issue in CHROME version 56.0.2924](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42082886/kendo-datepickerfor-issue-in-chrome-version-56-0-2924)
- [Kendo UI datepicker incompatible with Chrome 56](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41945417/kendo-ui-datepicker-incompatible-with-chrome-56)

Comment: <input id="testDate"  type="date" value="#dateformat(now(),'mm/dd/yyyy')#" name="testDate"  style="width:150px;"  required="required" validationMessage="Required" class="formdatepicker" />

if I am changing attribute type from date to text it seems working, but in old version it was working fine with type="date" attribute

Comment: @sreedevi yes, see the links

Comment: This link really helped me,Thank you