# How to set type="text" HtmlAttribute of KendoUI datepicker MVC control globally in a application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, datepicker

In continuation with the question [Kendo UI datepicker incompatible with Chrome 56](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41945417/kendo-ui-datepicker-incompatible-with-chrome-56), I want to set type = "text" property to HtmlAttributes of KendoUI datepicker controls in my project.

The number of controls are more and I cannot set one by one.

Is there a way to set it globally in a project without using a template? We have not used kendo template for datepicker.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
.Name("datepicker")
.Value("10/10/2011")
.HtmlAttributes(new { type = "text" }))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To apply globally with less effort you can make use of jQuery.

> jQuery code

```
$(function(){ 
    $('.k-datepicker input').attr('type','text');
});
```

Call this jQuery either on layout page or common.js (if any).